# Magento2 : How to access system.xml fields sortOrder parameter

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I would like to access the sortOrder parameter of some of the system.xml fields. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can able to access the sortOrder parameter of system.xml

Below is the sample field for sortOrder.

```
<field id="grid_per_page" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Products per Page on Grid Default Value</label>
    <comment>Must be in the allowed values list</comment>
    <validate>validate-per-page-value</validate>
</field>
```